# PERL: Cant use variables in Sybase SQL Driver to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, perl

I'm trying to use a dynamically constructed query to get data from an ms sql server(2008) in perl.

The sql-string looks like this:

```
$sql = (q/SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMNa) FROM TABLEa WHERE COLUMNb = '$var'/);
```

When I try to execute this I get the following error message:

```
DBD::Sybase::st execute failed:
  Server message number=245 severity=16 state=1 line=1 server=HOSTNAME
  text=Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '$var' to data type tinyint.
  at ./scriptname.pl line 32.
```

Comment: I am compelled to point out that you have the possibility of sql injection there.  You really should be looking at a [placeholders and bind values](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values).  Additionally, there is not enough information there (what is the definition of `TABLEa`? How are you executing the command? What is in `$var`?

Comment: oh well thats not web code im writing there - this is never gonna leave my workstation. TABLEa COLUMNb is indeed tinyint. the content of $var is a digit constructed in perl.

Comment: ok looks that my approach was wrong. I have to solve my original problem using T-SQL. My issue was that i didnt know how to loop in SQL. Guess this can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

q() is literal.  You need qq() if you want $var interpolated.

```
$sql = qq/SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMNa) FROM TABLEa WHERE COLUMNb = '$var'/;
```

Also, I agree with the comment on SQL injection.  You should use a bind variable instead.

Comment: thanks! that did it! and yes i know this aint sane code, this is a script im using on my workstation.